# Select event - Why is nothing displayed in the console?

Tags: javascript, events

Why is nothing displayed in the console when selecting text?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    dhksdh lsjkdlskdj s fjlkfjs d lsdjslkdj s sldjsldkj s
    <script>
        const onSelect = () => {
            console.log('onSelect text')
        }

        document.body.addEventListener('select', onSelect)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Maybe I wrote something wrong?

Comment: The `body` does not support/fire that [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select_event).

Comment: Maybe: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/selectionchange_event